# SSIS lookup a table with multiple business conditions

Tags: ssis, lookup

I need to do a lookup against a table with different business conditions on each column:

1. Against the first column is a "natural" lookup (equal).
2. Against the second column, the lookup is like : if they match, give me the result, if don't match, select the rows with empty fields.
3. Same thing this for the 3th, 4th, 5th column and eventually you just get one row, and the 6th column of this row is the matching value I need

My question is how to implement this logic against a lookup table with different business conditions on each column. Should I implement this with a store procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason for a stored procedure.   Just implement it in the SQL query used by the Lookup.

Comment: But I need to control the output of the select (if select A=B, then select, if Select A!=B, then select blank rows). Can I do this in a normal query?

Comment: Yes, with a CASE expression, or even with a carefully constructured WHERE clause.